# c# How to utilize Page_init, ViewState and Page_Load properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, pageload

I have been working with Web Forms for a short while now and I have read most of what I have found about this on google. However, I am still unclear on how to work with this properly. I like the picture in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863583/6320872), but find it a bit too generic. I have not found one decent, concrete example on how to work with these events.

I am currently creating several controls dynamically in code behind in the Page_Load event:

```cs
foreach (Service service in Services)
{
    // service div
    HtmlGenericControl serviceDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    serviceDiv.ID = service.ID;
    serviceDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
    outerDiv.Controls.Add(serviceDiv); //outerDiv exists in the aspx page

    // service updatepanel
    UpdatePanel uPanel = new UpdatePanel()
    {
        ID = service.ID + "_uPanel",
        UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
    };
    serviceDiv.Controls.Add(uPanel);

    // status span
    HtmlGenericControl statusSpan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    statusSpan.ID = service.ID + "_statusSpan";
    statusSpan.InnerHtml = service.Status;
    uPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(statusSpan);

    // show specific content
    if (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running.ToString()))
    {
        // status color
        statusSpan.Attributes.Add("class", "status-run");

        // stop button
        HtmlButton stopButton = new HtmlButton();
        stopButton.ID = service.ID + "_btnStop";
        stopButton.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-stop btn-red\"/></i>";
        stopButton.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
        stopButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        stopButton.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-link btn-xs");
        stopButton.Attributes.Add("title", "Stop");
        stopButton.ServerClick += new EventHandler(BtnStop_Click);
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(stopButton);
        uPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(stopButton);

        // restart button
        HtmlButton restartButton = new HtmlButton();
        restartButton.ID = service.ID + "_btnRestart";
        restartButton.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-refresh btn-blue\"/></i>";
        restartButton.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
        restartButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        restartButton.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-link btn-xs");
        restartButton.Attributes.Add("title", "Restart");
        restartButton.ServerClick += new EventHandler(BtnRestart_Click);
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(restartButton);
        uPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(restartButton);
    }
    else
    {
        // status color
        statusSpan.Attributes.Add("class", "status-stop");

        // start button
        HtmlButton startButton = new HtmlButton();
        startButton.ID = service.ID + "_btnStart";
        startButton.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-play btn-green\"/></i>";
        startButton.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
        startButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        startButton.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-link btn-xs");
        startButton.Attributes.Add("title", "Start");
        startButton.ServerClick += new EventHandler(BtnStart_Click);
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(startButton);
        uPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(startButton);
    }

    // version span
    HtmlGenericControl versionSpan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    versionSpan.ID = service.ID + "_version";
    versionSpan.InnerHtml = service.Version;
    versionSpan.Attributes.Add("class", "version-text");
    serviceDiv.Controls.Add(versionSpan);
```

What would I gain from creating these in Page_Init? If I create them in Page_Init, how do I access them in Page_Load? Private global lists of `UpdatePanel`s and `HtmlButton`s feels so unclean.

I know that the ViewState loads between Page_Init and Page_Load, but what does that really mean? Since I don't do full postbacks, but instead use `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl` to only update the `UpdatePanel`'s on postback, don't I need to re-populate in Page_Load?

Comment: I'm surprised the police haven't been round to close your question as too general!  Inany case,I can't give a tutorial on WebForms in a comment, but I'd consider adding the controls to the page markup.  E.g., you might have a Repeater whose template contains all the buttons and spans for a service.  Then DataBind the Repeater to a list of objects that contains relevant data about your Services.  I would have all controls present in the template, and set their visibility using a data-binding expression.  E.g.  the start and stop button visibility would be controlled by the service status.

Comment: @Joe I realize the title is a bit general, I could add a "in my case" but it just seems obvious that this would be the case, to me at least. The question itself however is clearly centered around my code and what the benefits would be in placing it in `Page_Init` over `Page_Load`. Why and how this affects ViewState and if I actually need it.

I would also suggest taking a shot at an actual answer instead of going with "I can't give a tutorial on WebForms in a comment". I haven't even gotten to repeaters and such yet (that's how new I am to Webforms) so a thorough answer would be appriciated.

Comment: @Skillzone, Markus has given a good answer, which I've just upvoted.  Basically the same advice as above, but better written.  Avoid creating controls dynamically, and instead include your controls in the ASPX markup, by using a Repeater and by setting the Visible property of controls as appropriate.  You say you haven't gotten to Repeaters yet: if so I respectfully suggest you learn about Repeaters and data-binding before you attempt to learn about how to add controls dynamically.

Comment: @Joe I agree that the answer is similar to your comment, I just commented on it asking for some further info. Well, dynamically programming controls came more natural to me since I am coming from a strict back-end background (Java and C). I have therefore tried to stay in the code behind as much as possible. Thus, my first google search were about learning how to add things from code behind. I have just recently started to run across the word `Repeater` while searching for other things, but didn't look further into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the ViewState, then you can also create the controls in `Page_Load`. The ViewState is used to store the values of the controls (which ones depends on the control) and to use them when the PostBack is sent to the server.

For instance, if you have a textbox, the PostBack contains the new value of the textbox and also the old value in the ViewState. The ASP.NET framework now compares those two and raises the `TextChanged` event if necessary. Without ViewState, this would not be possible.

The best advice you can give regarding dynamically created controls in ASP.NET WebForms is to avoid using them. They increase complexity very fast und are usually not necessary (even if it seems so at first).

In the majority of the cases, there is a much simpler approach, e.g. by using a Repeater. In your case, you have a list of services. You can bind this list to a Repeater and by that avoid to create the controls manually. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on how to use a Repeater.

Another upside of using a Repeater is that you can define the UI in the ASPX markup instead of in the code behind file. In your example, you change the UI based upon the status of the service. In this case, using the [ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.100).aspx)-event of the Repeater might be a good option.

Comment: The repeater approach does sound better. I'm not really familiar with them yet, reading up on them right now. I'm guessing the `Page_Init` becomes irrelevant then? Since the controls will be created in the ASPX markup and by the Repeater, and databinding should be done in `Page_Load`, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @Skillzore you will see that the Repeater approach is much simpler in the end. You won't need `Page_Init` and all the control creation stuff anymore. Typically, you set the `DataSource` of the Repeater in `Page_Load`. Only if you want to change the layout based upon the data itself (in your sample there is an if-statement based on the status of the service), you need to use `ItemDataBound`. I'd propose to start small, create a Repeater that outputs the service names, then add the common service layout to the template and add `ItemDataBound` in the end.

Comment: Yeah, I have started to try things out while reading about it. Just wanted to make sure that I didn't misplace the databinding. Seems to be working well so far. Thank you!

Don't know how you are with buttons and button events, but I would appreciate your input on another question I have https://stackoverflow.com/q/45055878/6320872. Thanks again!