# c# How to change button icon/formatting while "processing" button event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several server `HtmlButton`s created in code behind like this:

```cs
HtmlButton button = new HtmlButton();
button.ID = idString + "_btnStart";
button.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-play btn-green\"/></i>";
button.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
button.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
button.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-link btn-xs");
button.Attributes.Add("title", "Start");
button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(BtnStart_Click);
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(button);
```

The buttons all each have their own `UpdatePanel`:

```cs
UpdatePanel uPanel = new UpdatePanel()
{
    ID = idString + "_uPanel",
    UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
};
uPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(button);
```

Now, when the button is clicked I would like to first change the `InnerHtml` in the `Page_Load` event:

```cs
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Control control = null;
        string controlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (controlName != null && controlName != string.Empty)
        {
            control = FindControl(controlName);
            if(control != null)
            {
                HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton)control;
                UpdatePanel uPanel = (UpdatePanel)button.Parent.Parent;
                string id = button.ID.Split('_')[1];
                switch (id)
                {
                    case "btnStop":
                        button.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-red\"/></i>";
                        break;
                    case "btnStart":
                        button.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-green\"/></i>";
                        break;
                    case "btnRestart":
                        button.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-refresh fa-spin btn-blue\"/></i>";

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                uPanel.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the event, change it back when it is done:

```cs
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton)sender;
    Debug.WriteLine("Button clicked: " + button.ID);

    // sleeping to simulate process stuffs
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    button.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-play btn-green\"/></i>";
    (button.Parent.Parent as UpdatePanel).Update();
}
```

Is there a more "standard" approach to doing this or is this fine?

<s>At the moment it isn't working since the cast:</s>

```cs
UpdatePanel uPanel = (UpdatePanel)button.Parent;
```

Gives me an error:

> - $exception  {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel'."}  System.InvalidCastException

It Seems that the control I get from `button.Parent` can't be cast to anything. I need to call `(button.Parent as UpdatePanel).Update();` in `Page_Load` for this to work. Suggestions?

**Edit 1:**

Needed to call:

```cs
UpdatePanel uPanel = (UpdatePanel)button.Parent.Parent;
```

Since the first parent is the `ContentTemplateContainer`.

The code now runs without error, but the icon never changes to `fa-spinner` and then back. My intention is that it should in the above case show the `fa-spinner` for about 2 seconds then go back to its original icon.

**Edit 2:**

I am realizing that it is not possible to do this the way I am trying to, due to the page life cycle. The page is not rendering between the postback `Page_Load` and the button event. So even though the `InnerHtml` of the button has changed, it is never displayed. So I need a different approach to this.

Could we force a render of the `UpdatePanel` in question? Can we create a workaround to trigger the event twice? First time to change icon and do work and second time to change icon back? Other ideas?

Comment: I think because you didn't add the button to the update panel after creating it dynamically

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Oh, but I do, just after creating the update panel. ;)

Comment: When you call 'button.Parent' what does it show? I mean without casting to anything

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Needed to do button.Parent.Parent of course. The first parent is the `ContentTemplateContainer`. Now it finds the `UpdatePanel` and runs without error. I does not change the icon though.

Comment: Does your BtnStart_Click event fires when you click?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Yeah, it fires just fine. My intention however is for the button to change icon in the `Page_Load` of the postback and then to **change it back** at then end of the button event, when it is all done. Don't know if that is possible or if it should be done that way.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy I am realizing that it is not possible to do this the way I am trying to, due to the page life cycle. The page is not rendering between the postback `Page_Load` and the button event. So even though the `InnerHtml` of the button has changed, it is never displayed. So I need a different approach to this. Ideas?

Comment: @Skillzore do you can consider using the `OnClientClick` event?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I could, but don't know what difference that would make. I would need to make ajax calls then as well because I need server side event to happen. That's the "processing" part that I'm leaving out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said because of the page cycle you will not be able to see the icon change between page load and button click event.

So I would suggest in this case to use a little Javascript  as @Mauricio suggested in his comment.

You can add a new client event `OnClientClick="showIcon"`

```
function showIcon()
{
   document.getElementById('#myBtnId').innerHTML = <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-red'/></i>"
}
```

Now this icon will appear just after clicking the button on the client side and when he page refresh it will disappear based on your login the server side button click event.

For sure you will need to add your login in the javascript as it is not just as simple as I wrote, but I just wanted to give you my idea of how I would solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this.